# How can I add my class GroupAdmin to admin without getting errors?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

The following is my `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from register.models import Account, ProgramGroup


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'user_id', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'user_id')
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()


class GroupAdmin(ProgramGroup):
    list_display = ('group_id', 'group_name', 'group_token')


admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProgramGroup, GroupAdmin)
```

However, when I try to make migrations, I get the error

```
path('%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
AttributeError: 'GroupAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

If I get rid of `GroupAdmin` or `ProgramGroup` in the `admin.site.register` line, it will migrate, but then I can't see the `list_display` items in the admin interface. How should I correct this?

Comment: Can you add your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace ProgramGroup with **admin.ModelAdmin** in your class definition:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('group_id', 'group_name', 'group_token')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked except I changed it to ```class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)```